# Behavior of dataclasses import and class declaration in python REPL

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm attempting to understand some strange behavior around the python `dataclass` library when used interactively in a REPL. Basically, I've noticed that I get `TypeErrors` depending on the order and placement of the `from dataclass import dataclasses` statement relative to my class declaration.

Here is a minimal example of what I'm talking about.

Running:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = 'John'

p = Person()
p2 = Person(name = 'Jane')

print(p.name)
print(p2.name)
```

Results in:

```
John
Jane
```

However, if I first run the import statement:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
```

and then, separately run the class statement

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = 'John'

p = Person()
p2 = Person(name = 'Jane')

print(p.name)
print(p2.name)
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1 in line 5
      21     name: str = 'John'
      23 p = Person()
----> 24 p2 = Person(name = 'Jane')
      25 print(p.name)
      26 print(p2.name)

TypeError: Person() takes no arguments
```

Adding back in the import statement to the same cell block, and things work again. This is very confusing behavior. Making the default explicit with `field(default=)` doesn't seem to help.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = field(default='John')

p = Person()
p2 = Person(name = 'Jane')

print(p)
print(p2)
```

What is going on here? I'm running `python=3.10.9`

Comment: What happened to line 22 in the error message? What REPL are you using? It looks like `p2 = Person(name = 'Jane')` is somehow being executed *before* the decorator has actually been applied.

Comment: Your *code* is fine; this is a problem with your execution environment or how you are using it.

Comment: @chepner, line 22 is blank, so it was not included in the traceback. I admit this could be a problem with the execution environment. I'm using the interactive python functionality in VSCode. I would just be curious if there is any other mention of this kind of bug anywhere or an explanation of what could be different about executing in cell blocks vs a CLI REPL. I've never run into a bug like this before.

Comment: I seems like this is the bug responsible: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15058

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in my execution environment. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15058.

Per that thread, possible solutions:

- Copying an pasting code into the REPL
- Executing the file from the command line using python [script-path]
- Using "Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal" (shift + enter) if the decorator is indented as part of some scope (e.g. within an if statement or within a class definition)

Another fix I've found:

- Executing literally anything "above" the decorator.

Eg:

```
2+2
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = field(default='John')

p = Person()
p2 = Person(name = 'Jane')

print(p)
print(p2)
```

Works again. -_-

Comment: I've opened a new issue about this here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20810